# How do I calculate an updating average speed for each year in a table using c++?

Tags: c++

> In your program, you will have the user enter what percentage improvement in
>   rocket speeds (up to but not exceeding light speed!) each year. Your program will
>   then ask the user the maximum number of years that they are willing to wait on
>   earth before they leave. Use while loops in this step to implement simple error
>   checking by asking the user repeatedly until they give a valid input. Percentage
>   must be somewhere between 0 and 100 and the years waiting must be a positive
>   integer.
>
> Next, your program will generate a table using a for loop. That table will have
>   four columns with one row for leaving immediately followed by one row for each
>   year the user is willing to wait. The first column will contain the departure year.
>   The second column contains the rocket speed that rockets will be able to achieve
>   that year. The new rocket speed each year is calculated with this equation: 
>   velocity = velocity + (lightspeed - velocity) * (improvement/100)

I was able to correctly print out each year in the table I am trying to make, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use a loop to find the speed of the rocket for each year using a loop. I am pretty sure I am supposed to use a nested for loop, but with the code I have right now, it is stuck in an infinite loop. Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int percentIncrease = 0;
int maxYears = -1;
float speedLight = 299792;

while((percentIncrease <= 0) || (percentIncrease >= 100))
{
    cout << "What percentage do rocket speeds increase by each year?" << endl;
    cin >> percentIncrease;
}

while(maxYears < 0)
{
    cout << "What is the maximum number of years you are willing to wait on 
earth before you leave?" << endl;
    cin >> maxYears;
}

cout << "Start year|\tAvg Speed|\tEarth ETA|\tYour ETA" << endl;

for(int i = 2018; i  <= (maxYears + 2018); ++i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    for(int j = 10000; i <= (maxYears + 2018); j = j + (speedLight - j) * 
(percentIncrease/100))
    {
        cout << "\t" << j << endl;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good way to think about it is that you will have to print the table row by row. So your first for loop seems to be doing that.

In each row, you have to, first, print the year (starting with the current year) up until the maximum year. Making the first for loop iterate over the years is a good choice (i.e. making `i` go from `2018` until `maxYears + 2018`). Second, you have to print the speed for each year after calculating the improvement via the provided equation. (I'm assuming that in the problem description it was given that the first speed is 10000? If not, what is the starting value?) Because you will only print a number, you don't need a second for loop. Just calculate the new speed and print it. As for the third and fourth column, I'm not sure what is asked exactly, so for now it will be blank in the code.

I modified code based on my comments, plus a few other modifications related to my understanding of the problem description, coding best practices, and stylistic choices (read below the code for more info on why).

```
#include <iostream>
//--1
int main()
{
  //--2
  const float speedLight = 299792;
  const int startingYear = 2018;
  //--3
  float percentIncrease = 0;
  while ((percentIncrease <= 0) || (percentIncrease >= 100))
  {
    std::cout << "What percentage do rocket speeds increase by each year?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> percentIncrease;
  }
  //--4
  int maxYears = -1;
  while (maxYears < 1)
  {
    std::cout << "What is the maximum number of years you are willing to wait on earth before you leave? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> maxYears;
  }

  std::cout << "Year|\tAvg Speed|\tEarth ETA|\tYour ETA" << std::endl;
  //--5
  float currentSpeed = 10000;
  for (int year = startingYear; year <= (maxYears + startingYear); ++year)
  {
    //--6
    std::cout << year << "\t" << currentSpeed << std::endl;
    currentSpeed = currentSpeed + (speedLight - currentSpeed) * (percentIncrease / 100);
  }
  //--7
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

- --1: I removed unused libraries. (You may be using them for other parts
  of the program, like if you want to print float numbers). I also
  removed the `using namespace std;` because it is a bad practice. You
  can google it.
- --2: These numbers seem unchanging, so it is better to make them
  constants.
- --3: Maybe `percentIncrease` is not necessarily an integer.
- --4: The problem description states that the number of years is a
  positive  integer, so it cannot be `0`.
- --5: The currentSpeed (previously `j`) should be defined outside the
  loop because  it will be updated inside the loop. Plus, it is a float
  because of #3.
- --6: The speed should be printed after the year.
- --7: This is optional, in case you want the program window to not close
  immediately. You can alternatively debug there by putting a
  breakpoint, or any other solution.